# How to extract correct form of 2D array from dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm fairly new in Python and I want to load .mat files into python and plot multiple images that are 2D array. This is the code that I wrote. I was able to plot one image at the time, but when I loaded multiple .mat files (form of structure) into dict the form of array was different and I could not plot. 
2D arrays.

```
dataDir ="dir"
i=1 
mat=dict()
sig1=dict()
Sig=[]
oct_struct=dict()


for file in os.listdir( dataDir ) :
mat[i]=sio.loadmat( dataDir+file )
oct_struct[i]=mat[i]['Raw_Image']
sig1[i]=oct_struct[i]['sig1matrix']
i+=1
Sig=np.array(sig1[1]-0.)
```

This is how 2D array looks if I plot it from multiple dictionary

```
[array([[array([[579, 519, 496, ..., 640, 699, 656],
[550, 536, 505, ..., 633, 684, 616],
[548, 549, 492, ..., 622, 630, 690],
...,
[594, 532, 534, ..., 613, 527, 567],
[574, 564, 535, ..., 565, 601, 644],
[507, 534, 543, ..., 606, 614, 638]], dtype=uint16)]], dtype=object)]
```

Error that I received by plotting above array:

```
   imgplot=plt.imshow(Sig,cmap='jet')
   error'Image data cannot be converted to float'
```

This is how array looks if I extract array from one dict.

```
array(array([[579, 519, 496, ..., 640, 699, 656],
[550, 536, 505, ..., 633, 684, 616],
[548, 549, 492, ..., 622, 630, 690],
 ...,
[594, 532, 534, ..., 613, 527, 567],
[574, 564, 535, ..., 565, 601, 644],
[507, 534, 543, ..., 606, 614, 638]], dtype=uint16), dtype=object)
```

Comment: Change Sig=np.array(sig1[1]-0.) into Sig=np.array(sig1[1]-0.)[-1].

Comment: I tried it didn't work. I think the reason was the way that I loaded the mat files. I had to specify more detail in sio.loadmat